# Making a div nonclicable

Tags: html, css

I have a div and inside I have two clickable labels.
For some reason, the empty space within the div other than label is also getting clicked.

Is there any way to disable click inside A div other than for two labels?

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: please share some code you have tried . It seems unclear with only question.

Comment: share your code yar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `div` not clickable and `label` clickable

```
div{
  pointer-events:none;
}
label{
  pointer-events:all;
}
```

Comment: this still triggers click on a `div`

Comment: have you written any click event for your div? Please tell how you are handling the event for labels?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `css` using

```
pointer-events:none
```

or you can also do this in `JQuery` using

```
$('element').click(false)
```

Comment: this will prevent triggering click on child `label`

Comment: @Maximus True. See **AB Udhay's** answer

Answer (score 0):

Ad a click listener to the div and check for target property on the event. If it's the current element, call preventDefault()

HTML

```
<div>
    <label onclick="clickOnLabel1()">a</label>
    <label onclick="clickOnLabel2()">f</label>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (this === event.currentTarget) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use preventPropogation() ?